# constなオブジェクトへのポインタをdeleteしたときの挙動

Tags: c++

以下のコードはコンパイルし，動作します．(Wandboxのg++ 4.9.2,clang 3.5.0にて確認，以下同じ)

```
#include <new>
int main(){
    auto p = new int const(0);
    delete p;
}
```

しかし，delete p;を::operator delete(p);で置き換えた場合にはコンパイルエラーが発生してしまいます．（g++での例，clangでもコンパイルエラー）

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()': 
prog.cc:4:24: error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*' [-fpermissive] 
    ::operator delete(p);
```

確かにconstなオブジェクトへのポインタは非constなオブジェクトへのポインタには変換できませんし，operator deleteが非constなオブジェクトへのポインタを要求するのは理解できるのですが，ではなぜ最初のdelete式がコンパイル可能であるのかが分かりません．

N3797の§5.3.5.7より，

> Otherwise, the delete-expression will not call a deallocation function (3.7.4.2).

とあるので，`operator delete`の呼び出しが省略されたのかと考えましたが，以下のコードを実行してみたところ，`op delete`が出力されました．（bは無関係なオブジェクトでの呼び出しを避けるために使用しています）

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

bool b = false;
void operator delete(void*) noexcept{
    if(b){
        std::cout << "op delete" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    b = true;
    auto p = new int const(0);
    delete p;
    b = false;
}
```

この結果はどのように解釈すれば良いのでしょうか．

Answer (score 6, accepted):

同じく ISO/IEC 14882:1998 より
5.3.5 delete
1 delete-式 は最派生オブジェクトの解体であり
6 削除されるオブジェクトにデストラクタがあれば呼びだす
なので

> オブジェクトのdestructionであると解釈すれば

「解釈すれば」は要らないでしょう。

また 12.4 destructors に
「解体されるオブジェクトの占めている記憶域を解放する」系の文言は一切ありません。

一方で 3.7.3.2 operator delete はその名 [ 解放関数 ] のとおり
- デストラクタを起動するとは書かれていない
- 記憶域を解放する (義務がある) と書かれている

一般的実装としては operator delete が直ちに OS 等に直接資源を返すとは考えにくく
いわゆる free-store (に類する何か) に「未使用」マークを付けるだけ、が多いでしょう。
なので operator delete に const T* を渡すことには意味が無いと解釈すべきでしょう。
const だと「未使用」マークを付ける操作すらできないので。

だから一般的 C++ 実装としては
delete-expression に const/volatile T* が渡されたときの処理系の挙動は
1.  cv 修飾を除去する
2. デストラクタを呼ぶ (cv 修飾除去後の型で)
3. 最適解放関数を呼ぶ (cv 修飾除去後の型で)
となるものと思われます。

蛇足
pandaman 氏は当然わかっていて故意に書かれているのでしょうが第三者読者のために追記しておくと
提示サンプルの１
- new-式 + delete-式の組み合わせ＝正しい
- new-式 + operator delete の組み合わせ＝デストラクタが呼ばれないので正しくない

提示サンプルの２
- operator new は処理系提供のもので operator delete は自作＝記憶域は正しく解放されていない
すなわちメモリリークしている（デストラクタは呼ばれている）

ことだけ注意喚起しておきます。

Comment: destructionの定義が見つからなかったのでそう書いたのですが，おっしゃる通り§5.3.5.1に`The delete-expression operator destroys...`とありましたね．これと§12.4.2から，`delete-expression`ではオブジェクトのconst性は無視できると．

Answer (score 3):

ISO/IEC 14882:1998 によれば

5.3.5 delete
5.3.5-2 Note に const つき型へのポインタを渡してよい constness をキャストで除去する必要は無いとあります。

12.1 constructor, 12.4 destructor にも
12.1-4 constructor は const, volatile, const volatile オブジェクトに対して呼べる
  constructor が完了するまで const/volatile-ness は適用されない
12.4-2 destructor は const, volatile, const volatile オブジェクトに対して呼べる
　destructor が開始した時点で const/volatile-ness は適用されなくなる
とあります。

Comment: たしかに

>const and volatile
semantics (7.1.6.1) are not applied on an object under destruction. [§12.4.2]
とありますね．したがって，`delete-expression`がオブジェクトのdestructionであると解釈すれば，constなオブジェクトへのポインタであってもconst性が適用されず，`operator delete`を呼び出すことができると考えられそうです．

Answer (score 2):

まず，`delete-expression` は const ポインタを渡すことができますが，(§5.3.5.2 の Note) `::operator delete` の直接の呼び出しは delete-expression ではなく，単なる関数呼び出しなので，引数のポインタがそのまま渡され const ポインタを渡すことができません．
具体的には，`delete-expression`である delete はデストラクタの呼び出し後にオーバーロードを考慮した operator delete の呼び出しを行いますが， ::operator delete の直接の呼び出しではデストラクタが呼び出されず，引数のポインタがそのまま渡されます．

Comment: `delete-expression`に渡されたconstなオブジェクトへのポインタについて，operator deleteの呼び出しが行えるのはなぜでしょうか．処理系によってconst性が除去されているのでしょうか．

Comment: 確かに，`delete-expression による operator delete 呼び出しの際にconst性が除去されると`いった記述は見つかりませんね．

Comment: 「const性が除去される」のではなく、「デストラクタではconstを考慮しない」と解釈すべきだと思います。

Comment: デストラクタというよりは，deallocation functionである`operator delete`を呼び出す際に`delete-expression`の時だけconst性を無視できるのはなぜか，という点で疑問を感じています．